# Отправить сообщение в vk

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
import vk_api

from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import pymysql.cursors
import requests

# token
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="32cfe3bdd52b746e70181c352b7d2c8590ae62a4d65235693fb3d96cf4509bc822e2498edc3a934d71dba")



vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '190232052')

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.obj.from_id != '':
            if event.from_user:
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id=event.obj.from_id,
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    message=event.obj.text
                )
```

event.obj.from_id возвращает None.
event.obj.text тоже None. 
Как получить id и text?

Comment: Попробуйте `event.obj['peer_id']` и `event.obj['text']` для получения `peer_id` и `text` соответственно. Если не получится, то укажите, пожалуйста, версию `longPoll`, которую Вы используете.

Comment: Спасибо, решил. event.object.message['text']/event.object.message['from_id']

Answer (score 1):

Например чтобы отправить сообщение просто сформируйте словарь:

```
def write_aud_msg_chat(chat_id, attachment):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
```

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
```

Если же вы хотите авторизоваться с помощью пользователя просто укажите его токен (чтобы его получить перейдите по ссылке и скопируйте из адресной строки то что после acces_token= и до &: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2685278&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=https://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1 ):

```
vk1 = vk_api.VkApi(token=token1)
```

```
    peer_id = event.object.peer_id
    chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
    user = event.object.from_id
    mess = event.object.text.lower()
```

Сам код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
def write_msg_chat(chat_id, message):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        peer_id = event.object.peer_id
        chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
        user = event.object.from_id
        mess = event.object.text.lower()
        #тут реакция на различные команды
```